# How to set Blank excel cell using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a condition where in I need to check for the Delimiter in a string. If found then I need to set excel cell to blank. I have this code:

```
                row = sheet.createRow(newRow);
            for(String fieldValues: fieldList)
            {
                if(fieldValues.contains(","))
                {
                    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNo);
                    cell.setCellValue(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
                    cellNo++;
                }
                else
                {
                    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNo);
                    cell.setCellValue(fieldValues);
                    cellNo++;
                }
            }
```

Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK is not setting up the Blank Cell even I tried with cell.setCellValue("") but again it doesn't set. Does it try to skip that cell if we want to set a Blank Cell? if not then can anyone let me know how I can do that.

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: Is there something already in that cell?

Comment: No, if you see I am creating new row just before the for loop.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't already something in that row? Also, what do you mean by "is not setting up the Blank Cell"?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I want to set the blank value in cell

Comment: And what isn't working? Are you getting an exception? Some other value in the cell? Excel crashes?

Answer (score 14):

According to the Documentation and POI implementation I'd expect that

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
```

should do the trick and is all you need.

Answer (score 3):

I am a little late but,

dont think about setting the cell to be empty.
Think about leaving the cell empty.
When you create a Cell, it is empty by default until you set it's value.

try something like this:

```
            row = sheet.createRow(newRow);
        for(String fieldValues: fieldList)
        {
            if(fieldValues.contains(","))
            {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNo); //it's already blank here
                cellNo++;
            }
            else
            {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNo);
                cell.setCellValue(fieldValues);
                cellNo++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `setCellValue`. Instead use this method : `setCellStyle`

```
row = sheet.createRow(newRow);
for(String fieldValues: fieldList)
{
  if(fieldValues.contains(","))
  {
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNo);
    cell.setCellStyle(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
    cellNo++;
  }
  else
  {
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellNo);
    cell.setCellValue(fieldValues);
    cellNo++;
  }
}
```